# Add inline onclick to javascript generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to add an inline onclick event to javascript generated content and pass a variable at the same time?

```
ulList = '<li><a onclick="somefunction(data)"><span>Some text</span></a></li>';
```

I'm not getting the `somefunction()` to fire. It looks like everything is just a string. Which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes, that is possible and it should work (https://jsfiddle.net/v85xq6mp/). If it's not working for you then check the console for errors. I would assume the `somefunction()` is not defined in the correct scope. It's worth noting that inline event handlers should be avoided where possible. Delegated event handlers are a far better pattern to use for dynamic content

Comment: It's possible, but the scope and escaping rules make it a nightmare. Don't do it. Generate a DOM instead of a string of HTML. You're using jQuery so it can help. Embrace the `on` method.